# interfacing between Arduino and C#

Tags: arduino

I have used the Arduino Uno R3 to read the voltage and current of a solar panel.
I apply a certain voltage from manual power supply( which can be read through a voltage divider in my Arduino) and read the current through shunts in the Arduino as well. However , I need to use a programmed power supply to provide the voltage to the panel automatically instead of manually , this power supply is connected to my PC through Ethernet and its code is in C# , How can I interface between my Arduino code and the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is using a serial communication. You can connect either through the USB-to-serial converter onboard or using external hardware (other converters, bluetooth, ...).

On the arduino side you'll use the `Serial` (or `SoftwareSerial`) library, while on the pc you can use the `SerialPort` class. Just add one of those objects to your project, configure it in the proper way (port name, baud rate, ...) and attach to its `DataReceived` event.
In that event you will receive the bytes sent by the arduino. To send data to the arduino, then, you can use the `Write` function.

Comment: okay 
My Arduino is connected to com7 , can I use the same port in my C# code to send data to the Arduino

Comment: You MUST use the same com port. And you have to be sure that no other processes use the com7 port, otherwise your program won't be able to open it. Serial ports have an exclusive access...